# Not able to edit åäö correctly in file on remote server

Tags: macos, terminal, utf-8, character-encoding

When logging in to remote server (terminal, macos ventura) I experience issues with editing files (using vim) where åäö is not working correctly.

Capital ÅÄÖ is not working at all, and and odd space is inserted when entering lowercase åäö.

I have another macos machine running big sur, and logging in to the remote server through the terminal on that computer works just fine, so my conclusion is that it's not the remote server that is the issue but some odd setting in the macos - any ideas?

When running "locale" locally I get:

```
LANG="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Same settings on the big sur computer.

Tried:

1. The terminal setting "Set environemnt variable" in the Terminal app setting is checked on the big sur machine. I've both checked and unchecked (an restarted the Terminal app) on the ventura machine, but no difference.
2. Checked the .ssh/config - the only difference is that ventura requires

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

I don't see that making any difference in this matter.
Help with that to try next would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly *existing* instances of those character display correctly in VIM, but it's "just" keyboard input of those characters that fails? In that case it's *probably* unrelated to the LOCALE set up on either computer, but rather has to do with how your local terminal emulator interacts with the remote console. Maybe the `TERM` is set incorrectly. Do those characters work in a simple bash shell (i.e. can you type/execute `echo ÅÄÖ`) or does that show the same result as in vim?

Comment: You're right, I'm unable to type åäö in bash on the remote machine. I didn't make the connection! Any suggestions on what terms to search for to dig further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the help of this answer in the end:
https://superuser.com/questions/315202/terminal-in-os-x-lion-cant-write-%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6-on-remote-machine

I had that Q&A before, but I wasn't able to edit /etc/ssh/... and for some reason the penny didn't drop until I read Joachim Sauers comment (thank you!).

I edited the `~/.ssh/config`
added the line:

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

And now åäö works on remote machine.